# Remove sticky PDMS from glasses slides

Tags: polymers, glass

I prepared some PDMS mixing a Sylgard 186 (elastomer) and a curing agent with 10:1 ratio. I sucked all the bubbles and I sandwiched the PDMS between two glass slides to get flat surfaces. Finally I heated up at 60C for 6 hours. Now I would like to get my PDMS by removing one of the two glass slides, but it is practically impossible...

Does anyone have some suggestions to overcome this issue?